# What am I doing wrong that my python image is so large

Tags: docker

I have tried
From Python:3 from winamd/python, python latest, etc....
and I get 11.3 GB image.

I have pulled various versions, tried it without the microsoft base, it always comes back huge

Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

FROM winamd64/python:3

COPY /dist/requirements_dev.txt /dist/

python -m pip install -r /dist/requirements_dev.txt

COPY /src /

CMD ./app.bat
```

```
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

ss                                     latest              e87e3348b396        27 hours ago        13.1GB

none>              65f41cd852bd        27 hours ago        13.1GB

none>              f080b61d8285        27 hours ago        11.8GB

none>              ac6d42c7d5a4        27 hours ago        11.3GB

none>              6f56b283cccb        27 hours ago        11.3GB

winamd64/python                        3.7.4               3623371a043f        47 hours ago        11.3GB

mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore   ltsc2019            b05c49cadc10        2 weeks ago         4.71GB
```

is what I get.
I expect numbers in the MB wouldn't I?

Comment: wow.... 11.4Gb for the base image only? I've got to check that

Comment: the base image is 6Gb... it's really big but not as big as yours. src: https://hub.docker.com/r/winamd64/python/tags

Comment: did you try with with the basic python:3.7? Replace the FROM entries with `FROM python:3.7`

Comment: To answer the question above, I've tried allot of various Python versions, but I did not expect this size.  If you all are saying the base image of Python should be 6GB then that on top of windows is about 11.... but this just seems Crazy large.   6 GB sounds crazy large.  Someone has a windows/python base that is small.  if you do can I see that.  I'll start trying some tricks, but any advice is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output, you seem to have a multistage build (not completely sure if that's how Windows handles the multiple FROM lines) with the final build image being `winamd64/python:3`

Your `winamd64/python:3` image is 11.3GB.  You then go on to install additional `python` modules which would take up more space.

The only fix for this would be to start with a smaller base image, as your new image will build upon that.  As mentioned in the comments, the official size of `winamd64/python:3` is 6GB, so any image built on top of that will be larger.

Comment: I don't know how docker on windows works under the hood but having multiple FROM should behave as a multistage build. Only the last base image remains, the rest gets discarded. Moreover the size of the base image is already 11.3 Gb according to his system.